# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in swift with getting data from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am connecting to Firestore from iOS.

But when I ran this code it gave me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

```
db.collection("chats").document(code).setData(["users":[Constants.User.currentUID!]]) { (err) in
    if err != nil{
        print("error registering with firebase")
    }
    else{
        //...
    }
}
```

So I went to the scheme editor and enabled the `Address Sanitizer`.

The error I got was highlighting `code` and said:

> Thread 1: Use of deallocated memory

When I click on `code` it does show its correct value of `QAWQ`

What do I do?

**EDIT**

Under further investigation it is wherever the variable `code` is used

Comment: Where is code defined? What else do you do with it? The current amount of information is unlikely to be enough to solve this problem.

Comment: make sure that you have set up your project as [mentioned here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#ios)

Comment: Please safely unwrap optionals instead of force unwrapping then; like you're doing here `Constants.User.currentUID!`. You should protect your code by safely unwrapping that and if it's not nil, then processed. We don't know what `code` is and it could be nil, or an illegal character or some kind of other object that can't be used there. Please clarify your question and include enough so we know what you're attempting to do. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)